# "Comparing coefficients" in the context of Bernoulli numbers

Tags: number-theory, bernoulli-numbers

I'm currently studying Bernoulli numbers and I ended up with
$$1=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^k \dbinom{k+1}{n}\mathrm B_{n}\right)\dfrac{z^k}{(k+1)!}.$$
Now, "comparing coefficients" should yield
$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^k \dbinom{k+1}{n}\mathrm B_{n}=0,$$
but I don't understand that step of "comparing coefficients". Also, why are the Bernoulli numbers extracted from this correct only for $k\gt 0$? What caused the loss of generality?

Comment: Younare comparing coefficients between the RH series and the LH series which is actuallt only 1+0z+0z^2+...

Comment: Oh, I see that now. So it's actually $\sum_{n=0}^k \binom{k+1}{n}\mathrm B_{n}=1$ if $k=0$ and $\sum_{n=0}^k \binom{k+1}{n}\mathrm B_{n}=0$ if $k\gt 0$.

Comment: Exactly, here we go